# AMP - Hide a div on page load based on local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage, amp-html

In the AMP page on page load, I need to hide a div if the local storage "enable-modal" is true. I cannot achieve it without user interaction. Need help here, please.

> [amp-script] AMP.setState only updated page state and did not
> reevaluate bindings due to lack of recent user interaction.

Comment: I will recommend using local storage with amp script, I will attempt this on weekend meantime you may check this out https://github.com/milindmore22/amp-local-storage/

Comment: I need to show or hide a div once the AMP page is loaded based on local storage.

Comment: how you are creating AMP pages? are you using CMS like WordPress?

Comment: I am creating AMP and non-AMP pages at the same time using a static site generator. For site configuration, we use static site generator [metalsmith](http://metalsmith.io/), ES6, Webpack & NodeJs. I also use HTML preprocessor pugJs.